# Google Apps Scriptで「このアプリはブロックされます」

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Chrome上のGoogle Spreadsheetで、とあるGoogle Apps Scriptを実行すると、「承認が必要です」のポップアップが出て、次にユーザを選択すると、そのまま「このアプリはブロックされます」という画面が出て実行できません。

[image: 「このアプリはブロックされます」のスクリーンショット]

Google Apps Scriptの実行ログには「このプロジェクトを実行するには、ご利用の Google アカウントへのアクアセスを許可する必要があります。再試行して、許可してください。」(原文ママ) と出ます。

[image: 「このプロジェクトを実行するには、ご利用の Google アカウントへのアクアセスを許可する必要があります。再試行して、許可してください。」のスクリーンショット]

Googleのサポートとやりとりをして、以下の確認を行いました。

- Google Workspaceに所属するアカウントかどうか? → No、個人のアカウントである。
- シークレットモードで実行するとどうなるか? → 変わらず。
- キャッシュやCookieを削除するとどうなるか? → 変わらず。
- 拡張機能を全てオフにするとどうなるか? → 変わらず。
- Chromeを更新してみてはどうか? → 変わらず。
- 安全性の低いアプリの許可をオフにするとどうなるか? → 2要素認証を有効にしているとオフにできないと出る。
- 2要素認証をオフにして、安全性の低いアプリの許可をオフにするとどうなるか? → 「この設定は、お使いのアカウントでは利用できません。」と出る。

これらの助言は全て問題解決に寄与しませんでした。そして、最後にGoogleのサポートは以下のような助言をしてくれました。

> また、当窓口ではGoogle App Script について詳細な資料がないため、お手数おかけしますが、下記 URL からスタック・オーバーフローに当事象についてご投稿いただけますと幸いでございます。

ということで、この投稿に至ります。Twitterで検索すると、2022年12月頃に同様の現象に遭遇されていた人を観測することができます。またこのブロックが発生すると、一定期間ブロックが継続する、ということもGoogleのサポートからお聞きしました。その一定期間がどの程度であるかについては明言を避けられておりましたが、ゆえに何らかのアクションを行っても、それが一定期間ブロックによるものなのか、あるいは効果のないアクションだったのかを切り分けすることが難しいことが、この問題の解決を困難とする一因となっていると言えましょう。

もし解決の糸口をお持ちの方がおられましたら、あるいは同様の問題に煩わされている同好の志がおられましたら、ぜひわいわいしていただければ幸いです。

Comment: スクリプトの動作でブロックされているのであれば、その中身が分からない事には第三者は判断のしようが無いと思います。質問はあとからでも編集できるので、必要に応じて内容を見直してください。

Comment: 同じ状況かどうかはわかりませんが、こちらスレッドは役に立ちそうでしょうか。https://stackoverflow.com/q/66633659