# このアプリはブロックされます　が突破できない

Tags: google-apps-script

Google App Scrptを使いたいのですが、Scriptを実行した際、添付の通りこのアプリはブロックされます　と表示され、GASが使用できません。

・試したこと
ChromeやEdgeでの実行
2段階認証を削除して実行

・前提条件
アカウント：個人（@gmailのアカウント）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 具体的な中身が分からない事には第三者は判断のしようが無いと思います。質問はあとからでも編集できるので、必要に応じて内容を見直してください。

Comment: 過去の類似質問 (コメント欄に参考情報あり) : [Google Apps Scriptで「このアプリはブロックされます」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/95529)